# Custom tooltip with Rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to implement my custom tooltip on a diagram using `vis-network` library and RXJS.

The main principle is:

- One observable `diagramElementHover$` to show the tooltip
- One observable `hideTooltipObs$` to hide the tooltip (the emitted value is `null`)
- I want the tooltip to wait 1000ms to check if the mouse pointer is still under the element to be displayed (clear the tooltip if the pointer has gone before that delay)
- The tooltip display uses the `*ngIf` directive with `tooltip` value

For now, the problem is that I can't prevent the tooltip to be shown if the user hovers one element and stays less that 1 second (then the tooltip is not hidden, unless you enter another node)

Globally, my implementation looks like this:

```js
this.sub = merge(
    diagramElementHover$.pipe(
        mergeMap(event => of(event).pipe(delay(1000))),
        repeat()
    ),
        hideTooltipObs$
    ).pipe(
        tap(tooltip => this.tooltip = tooltip)
    )
```

I tried to use the `takeUntil()` operator but without success... 
Can you guide me through this?

Here is the stackblitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ucyie7).

Comment: What is the main use case for the following scenario:

I want the tooltip to wait 1000ms to check if the mouse pointer is still under the element to be displayed (clear the tooltip if the pointer has gone before that delay)

Can you clarify a little bit?

Comment: You also need to think about listening to mouse pointer position before showing the tooltip. Because now if a node is moved somewhere else and held for more than a second, the tooltip is going to show up in the node's old position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `switchMap` on the merged subjects.

The `delay` should then be inside the `switchMap`.

```
this.sub = merge<any>(
    diagramElementHover$.pipe(
      map(event => event),
      repeat()
    ),
    hideTooltipObs$
).pipe(
    switchMap(tooltip => {
      return of(tooltip).pipe(
        delay(tooltip ? 1000 : 0),
        tap(() =>this.tooltip = tooltip ))
    })
).subscribe()
```

Here my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hover-problem)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set the tooltip reference as null in the hide tooltip observable to ensure it will remove the tooltip on hide:

```js
const hideTooltipObs$ = merge(
    new Observable<null>(obs => this.network.on('selectNode', () => obs.next(null))),
    new Observable<null>(obs => this.network.on('blurEdge', () => obs.next(null))),
    new Observable<null>(obs => this.network.on('blurNode', () => obs.next(null)))
).pipe(tap(() => {
  console.log('hide tooltip');
  this.tooltip = null;
}))
```

2. Then you have to add inside the mergeMap delay the `takeUntil` operator. The idea here is to keep the reference of delaying to show the tooltip **until** the hide is trigerred.

```js
 mergeMap(event => of(event).pipe(
     delay(1000),
     takeUntil(hideTooltipObs$),
  )
),
```

Take a look in this stackblitz: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gfj1gg

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vis-nodes?file=src/app/app.component.ts) could be an approach in which you don't have to manually subscribe:

#### app.component.html

```html
<div *ngIf="tooltip$ | async as tooltip"
     class="diagram-tooltip"
     [style.top.px]="tooltip.y"
     [style.left.px]="tooltip.x">
     <p>{{ tooltip.text }}</p>
</div>
```

#### app.component.ts

```js
const diagramElementHover$ = merge(
    fromEventPattern(handler => this.network.on('hoverNode', handler))
      .pipe(
        map<any, any>(params => ({ event: params.event, element: this.nodes.find(n => n.id === params.node) }))
      ),

    fromEventPattern(handler => this.network.on('hoverEdge', handler))
      .pipe(
        map<any, any>(params => ({ event: params.event, element: this.edges.find(e => e.id === params.edge) }))
      ),
    ).pipe(
        map(obj => ({
          text: obj.element.label,
          x: obj.event.offsetX + 10,
          y: obj.event.offsetY + 10
        })
      )
    );

  const hideTooltipObs$ = merge(
      fromEventPattern(handler => this.network.on('selectNode', handler)),
      fromEventPattern(handler => this.network.on('blurEdge', handler)),
      fromEventPattern(handler => this.network.on('blurNode', handler)),
  ).pipe(
    mapTo(null), 
    tap(() => console.log('hide tooltip')),
    publish(),
    refCount(),
  );

  const showTooltip$ = diagramElementHover$.pipe(
    switchMap(
      obj => 
        timer(1000).pipe(
          takeUntil(hideTooltipObs$),
          isEmpty(),
          map(isEmpty => isEmpty ? null : obj)
        ),
    )
  );

  const hideToolTip$ = hideTooltipObs$;

  this.tooltip$ = merge(showTooltip$, hideToolTip$);
```

Let's go through each relevant part.

`fromEventPattern` simply provides a way to convert an API to an Observable.

In the cases above, it creates an Observable that will emit whenever the **handler function** is called.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62037167/9632621).

```js
const hideTooltipObs$ = merge(
    /* ... */
).pipe(
  mapTo(null), 
  tap(() => console.log('hide tooltip')),
  publish(),
  refCount(),
);
```

`publish()` + `refCount()` will multicast the results by placing a `Subject` instance between the data producer(`hideTooltipObs$`) and the data consumers(e.g `hideTooltipObs$.pipe().subscribe()`). This is needed as `hideTooltipObs$` is subscribed in multiple places.

```js
const showTooltip$ = diagramElementHover$.pipe(
  switchMap(
    obj => 
      timer(1000).pipe(
        takeUntil(hideTooltipObs$),
        isEmpty(),
        map(isEmpty => isEmpty ? null : obj)
      ),
  )
);
```

Whenever `diagramElementHover$` emits, start a timer (`timer(1000)`) that will complete when either `1s` has passed or `hideTooltipObs$` emits(due to `takeUntil`). `isEmpty()` will emit `true` if the source completed **without** emitting any values and `false` otherwise.

If `isEmpty === true`, it means that `hideTooltipObs$` emitted before `1s` had passed.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, is there a reason to use `fromEventPattern` instead of creating a `new Observable()` as I did?

Comment: It's more personal preference here, but I'd say you end up having less lines of code. If you need to have some teardown logic(e.g null out some variables, remove ev listeners), you can provide a second fn to `fromEventPattern` and there you can put that logic. Similarly, an Observable specifies a teardown logic by returning another function: `new Observable(s => { ..., return () => { teardown logic } })`